# Making templatized optimization more maintainable

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, enums

Sometimes a piece of code can be better-optimized by the compiler by using a templatized internal implementation for an invariant. For example, if you have a known number of channels in an image, instead of doing something like:

```
Image::doOperation() {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; i j mChannels; j++) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

you can do this:

```
template<unsigned int c> Image::doOperationInternal() {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

Image::doOperation() {
    switch (mChannels) {
        case 1: doOperation<1>(); break;
        case 2: doOperation<2>(); break;
        case 3: doOperation<3>(); break;
        case 4: doOperation<4>(); break;
    }
}
```

which allows the compiler to generate different unrolled loops for the different channel counts (which can in turn vastly improve runtime efficiency and also open up different optimizations such as SIMD instructions and so forth).

However, this can often expand into some fairly large case statements, and any method which has been optimized in this way must have the unrolled case statement.  So, let's say that instead we had an `enum Format` for the known image formats (where the value of the enum happens to map to the channel count).  Since the enum only has a certain range of known values, there is a temptation to try this:

```
template<Image::Format f> Image::doOperationInternal() {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < static_cast<unsigned int>(f); j++) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

Image::doOperation() {
    const Format f = mFormat;
    doOperationInternal<f>();
}
```

However, in this case the compiler (rightfully) complains that f is not a constant expression, even though it has only a finite range and in theory the compiler could generate the `switch` logic to cover all of the enumerated values.

So, my question: is there an alternate approach which will allow the compiler to generate invariant-value-optimized code without requiring a switch-case explosion per function invocation?

Comment: I think you can get close with something like boost::variant (i.e. a type-safe union). You still have to enumerate all the `c` values you want to support, but that enumeration is more compact. I think the general solution is a code generator.

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure how boost::variant helps in this case... could you try formulating a means of doing it and post an answer? :)

Comment: A channel should contain millions of image pixels, so I think the overhead of the loop through all the channels is negligible compared to the workload of processing each channel.   Did you really observe any substantial difference in runtime performance before and after your "optimization"?

Comment: @nodakai yes, this is pretty significant.  And a common optimization.  If A is large, A*B is sensitive in B.: meanwhile A+B is not.  The innermost code in per pixel ops is the multiplication case.

Comment: Modest setup costs are ok, right?  Like O(n) in number of cases per image?  O(lg n) with large constant?  Or once per program execution O(n)?  (per image n easiest, then per execution, and lg n solution is a serious mess)

Comment: Ok, I implemented the O(n) once C++03 version, where a jump table is created `static`ly for each case and then reused, with a toy example that just prints out the compile time value to `std::cout`.

Comment: Templates are a bad way to write the code you actually have in your question.  Read up on "Duff's Device".

Comment: @BenVoigt I kept the example simpler than the reality because I didn't want the meat of the optimization itself to get in the way of that which I was trying to improve.

Comment: I edited the question to make it a bit more obvious what the situation is and why this optimization is useful. The inner loop is small and has different optimizations available based on SIMD instructions, etc., whereas the outer loop is large. Believe me, this makes a HUGE difference, especially on CPUs with lousy branch prediction or with SIMD instructions available.

Answer (score 4):

Make jump table array, then invoke.  The goal is to create an array of the various functions, then do an array lookup and call the one you want.

First, I'll do the C++11 one.  C++1y contains its own integral sequence types, and has easy to write `auto` return types: the C++11 one will return `void`.

Our functor class looks something like this:

```
struct example_functor {
  template<unsigned N>
  static void action(double d) const {
    std::cout << N << ":" << d << "\n"; // or whatever, N is a compile time constant
  }
};
```

In C++11, we will want some boilerplate:

```
template<unsigned...> struct indexes {};
template<unsigned Max, unsigned... Is> struct make_indexes:make_indexes< Max-1, Max-1, Is... > {};
template<unsigned... Is> struct make_indexes<0, Is...>:indexes<Is...> {};
```

to create and pattern match packs of indexes.

The interface then looks like:

```
template<typename Functor, unsigned Max, typename... Ts>
void invoke_jump( unsigned index, Ts&&... ts );
```

and is called like:

```
invoke_jump<example_functor, 10>( 7, 3.14 );
```

We first create a helper:

```
template<typename Functor, unsigned... Is, typename... Ts>
void do_invoke_jump( unsigned index, indexes<Is...>, Ts&&... ts ) {
  static auto table[]={ &(Functor::template action<Is>)... };
  table[index]( std::forward<Ts>(ts)... )
}
template<typename Functor, unsigned Max, typename... Ts>
void invoke_jump( unsigned index, Ts&&... ts ) {
  do_invoke_jump( index, make_indexes<Max>(), std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
}
```

which creates a `static` table of `Functor::action` then does a lookup on them and invokes it.

In C++03 we don't have `...` syntax, so we have to do more things manually, and no perfect forwarding.  What I'll do is create a `std::vector` table instead.

First, a cute little program that runs `Functor.action<I>()` for I in [Begin, End) in order:

```
template<unsigned Begin, unsigned End, typename Functor>
struct ForEach:ForEach<Begin, End-1, Functor> {
  ForEach(Functor& functor):
    ForEach<Begin, End-1, Functor>(functor)
  {
    functor->template action<End-1>();
  }
};
template<unsigned Begin, typename Functor>
struct ForEach<Begin,Begin,Functor> {};
```

which I will admit is overly cute (the chain is implicitly created by the constructor dependencies).

We then use this to build a `vector` up.

```
template<typename Signature, typename Functor>
struct PopulateVector {
  std::vector< Signature* >* target; // change the signature here to whatever you want
  PopulateVector(std::vector< Signature* >* t):target(t) {}
  template<unsigned I>
  void action() {
    target->push_back( &(Functor::template action<I>) );
  }
};
```

We can then hook the two up:

```
template<typename Signature, typename Functor, unsigned Max>
std::vector< Signature* > make_table() {
  std::vector< Signature* > retval;
  retval.reserve(Max);
  PopulateVector<Signature, Functor> worker(&retval);
  ForEach<0, Max>( worker ); // runtime work basically done on this line
  return retval;
}
```

which builds our jump table as a `std::vector`.

We can then call the Ith element of the jump table easily.

```
struct example_functor {
  template<unsigned I>
  static void action() {
    std::cout << I << "\n";
  }
};
void test( unsigned i ) {
  static std::vector< void(*)() > table = make_table< void(), example_functor, 100 >();
  if (i < 100)
    table[i]();
}
```

which when passed the integer `i` prints it and then a newline.

The signature of the function in the table can be whatever you want, so you can pass in a pointer to a type and invoke a method, with `I` being a compile-time constant.  The `action` method does have to be `static`, but it can call non-`static` based methods of its arguments.

The big differences in C++03 is that you need different code for different signatures of the jump table, a lot of machinery (and a `std::vector` instead of a static array) to build the jump table.

When doing serious image processing, you'll want to have scanline functions generated this way, with per-pixel operations possibly embedded in it somewhere in the generated scanline function.  Doing a jump-dispatch once per scanline is usually fast enough, unless your images are 1 pixel wide and a billion pixels tall.

The above code still needs auditing for correctness: it was written without being compiled.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well, but I don't fully understand what you're doing. Could you expand this further for @fluffy's example?

Comment: I'm with @Adam on that - looks like a kernel of a great answer but I really don't understand the answer (and I thought I was reasonably knowledgeable about this stuff!).  Also, I'd prefer something that doesn't require C++11 (boost is fine, but I'm stuck supporting g++ 4.1)

Comment: Without 11 is hard: more detail is easy.  Just wrote that in a taxi, so kept it brief.  I can do it in 03, but we end up with a chain of `if`s (possibly binary tree), which only works well if the branch is far from the work, and the work is repeated.  Otoh, is an initial inefficient setup at runtime acceptable?  (so slow setuo, fast branch?)

Comment: @Adam More exposition added.  Including C++03 version.  The C++03 version rather sucks, but what you gonna do?

Comment: The C++11 version of this is nice for when C++11 is something I can use.  I think I like @mattnewport's better, though, in terms of ease of understanding and portability and so on (and the tiny extra bit of per-call overhead isn't something to worry about - who cares about a few extra branches at call time when it's about speeding up a tight inner loop by a huge factor?), but this still gets a +1 from me just because it taught me a lot of stuff I didn't know.

Comment: @fluffy good point -- I spent too much effort on making it support N different cases, while you only need 4.

Answer (score 1):

Yakk's C++11/1y technique is great but if the C++03 version is a bit too much template trickery for you there's a simpler / less elegant version that at least avoids the copy and paste of switch statements and gives you only one switch statement to maintain:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
    template<unsigned int c>
    static void Action() {
        std::cout << "c: " << c << endl;
    }
};

template<typename F>
void Dispatch(unsigned int c) {
    switch (c) {
    case 1: F::Action<1>(); break;
    case 2: F::Action<2>(); break;
    case 3: F::Action<3>(); break;
    }
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        Dispatch<Foo>(i);
}
```

Comment: That's pretty cute, and I think it would be usable even when each action has a different parameter count (since the params can be bound in the action ctor).  Much nicer than my current #define hack, in any case. I might end up using it. Thanks! :)

Comment: ...although actually making use of this for a method on an object is a LITTLE tricky. Either you have to pass in the object as a self ref (and have this operate externally), or you have a struct per method which then just delegates to the method itself. Still, it's a good technique to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, here's my (temporary) solution that I went with in the meantime:

```
#define DISPATCH_TEMPLATE_CALL(func, args) do { \
    switch (mChannels) { \
    case 1: func<1> args; break; \
    case 2: func<2> args; break; \
    case 3: func<3> args; break; \
    case 4: func<4> args; break; \
    default: throw std::range_error("Unhandled format"); \
    } \
} while (0)

template<unsigned int n> void Image::doSomethingInternal(a, b, c) {
    // ...
}

void Image::doSomething(a, b, c) {
    DISPATCH_TEMPLATE_CALL(doSomethingInternal, (a, b, c));
}
```

which is obviously not a preferable approach. But it works.